# Xpath is inconsistent for an xml

Tags: java, xpath, dom4j

I have the following xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<qdbapi>
   <action>****</action>
   <errcode>0</errcode>
   <errtext>No error</errtext>
   <qid>****</qid>
   <qname>****</qname>
   <table>
      <fields>
         <field id="19" field_type="text" base_type="text" />
      </fields>
      <records>
         <record>
            <f id="6">1</f>
         </record>
         <record>
            <f id="6">1</f>
         </record>
         <record>
            <f id="6">1</f>
         </record>
      </records>
   </table>
</qdbapi>
```

I use dom4j for extracting the records from the xml. The following xpath works:

```
//qdbapi//fields//field
```

The following path works upto //qdbapi/records but not //qdbapi//records//record

```
//qdbapi//records//record
```

Both xpaths (fields, records) work in xpath online testers but not in code.

The code is as follows:

```java
    XmlByteArrayStream = NewJavaObject("java.io.ByteArrayInputStream", {xmlStringBytes});
    SAXReaderObj = NewJavaObject("org.dom4j.io.SAXReader", {});
    XMLDOMDocObj = JavaCall("org.dom4j.io.SAXReader", SAXReaderObj, "read", { XmlByteArrayStream } );
    SelectedNodes = JavaCall('java.util.ArrayList',XMLDOMDocObj,"selectNodes",{"//qdbapi//records"});
    SelectedNodesSize = JavaCall(null,SelectedNodes,"size",{});
    SelectedRecordElement = JavaCall('java.util.ArrayList',SelectedNodes,"get",{0});
    Log(PolicyName + " " +"QBQueryResult:" +SelectedNodesSize);
    recordSelectedNodeChildElements = JavaCall('java.util.ArrayList',SelectedRecordElement,"selectNodes",{"//record"});
    SelectedNodeChildElementsSize = JavaCall(null,recordSelectedNodeChildElements,"size",{});
    Log(PolicyName + " " +"QBQueryResult:" +SelectedNodeChildElementsSize);//printed size is zero
```

Comment: #1: Why is the XPath using multiple //? // would be "root of document", making your Xpath jump root->elementlist->back to root->new element list->back to root. Without the multiple // selecting a record would become "//qdbapi/records/record". (not sure why the dom4j is behaving like that for the two XPaths)

Comment: This absolute expression `//qdbapi//records//record` is not the same than `//record` absolute expression. Both begin the selection from de document root. If you want a relative expression from some context node you might supply to your API, it would be better `.//record`

Answer (score 0):

DOM4J behaves as expected. This snippet:

```
static String XML =
        "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>\n" +
        "<qdbapi>\n" +
        "   <action>****</action>\n" +
        "   <errcode>0</errcode>\n" +
        "   <errtext>No error</errtext>\n" +
        "   <qid>****</qid>\n" +
        "   <qname>****</qname>\n" +
        "   <table>\n" +
        "      <fields>\n" +
        "         <field id='19' field_type='text' base_type='text' />\n" +
        "      </fields>\n" +
        "      <records>\n" +
        "         <record>\n" +
        "            <f id='6'>1</f>\n" +
        "         </record>\n" +
        "         <record>\n" +
        "            <f id='6'>1</f>\n" +
        "         </record>\n" +
        "         <record>\n" +
        "            <f id='6'>1</f>\n" +
        "         </record>\n" +
        "      </records>\n" +
        "   </table>\n" +
        "</qdbapi>";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Document doc = new SAXReader().read(new StringReader(XML));
    doc.selectNodes("//qdbapi//fields/field")
        .forEach((e) -> System.out.println(e.getName()));
    System.out.println();
    doc.selectNodes("//qdbapi//records//record")
        .forEach((e) -> System.out.println(e.getName()));
}
```

produces the following output:

```
field

record
record
record
```

The problem is surely with your code (which looks very strange btw), not with DOM4J.